# What is MongoDB aggregate pipeline?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Using Mongoose driver

Consider the following code :

**Connecting to database**

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require("dotenv").config();

mongoose.connect(process.env.DB);
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: String }, {collection: 'test'});
const Model = mongoose.model('test', userSchema);
```

**Creating dummy document**

```js
async function createDocs() {
    await Model.deleteMany({});
    await Model.insertMany([{name: "User1"}, {name: "User2"}, {name: "User3"},{name: "User4"}])
}
createDocs();
```

**Filtering data using `Model.find()`**

```js
async function findDoc () {
    let doc = await Model.find({name: 'User1'});
    console.log(`Using find method : ${doc}`);
}
findDoc();
```

**Filtering data using `Model.aggregate()`**

```js
async function matchDoc() {
    let doc = await Model.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {name : 'User1'}
        }
    ])
    console.log(`Using aggregate pipeline : `, doc);
}
matchDoc();
```

• *Both the processes produce the same output*

Q1) What is an aggregate pipeline and why use it?

Q2) Which method of retrieving data is faster?

Answer (score 1):

1. I will not get too much into this as there is a lot of information online. But essentially the aggregation pipeline gives you access to a lot of strong operators - mainly used for data analysis and object restructuring, for simple `get` and `set` operations there is no use for it.

A "real life" example of when you'd want to use the aggregation pipeline is if you want to calculate an `avg` of a certain value in your data, obviously this is just the tip of the iceberg in terms of power that this feature allows.

2. `find` is slightly faster, the aggregation pipeline has some overhead when compared to the query language as each stage has to load the BSON documents into memory, where `find` doesn't. If your use case is indeed just a simple query then `find` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking a smaller piece of the aggregation pipeline.

1. You cannot do pipeline with a single query using `find`

Let's say you want to find all the orders which have a product that was purchased within a duration. Here, orders and customers are two different collections, You need multiple stages.

2. Let's say you stored data in a different format, For ex, date as a string, integers as a decimal. If you want to convert on the fly, you can use aggregation.
3. If you want to use aggregation operators in an update operation from mongo 4.2+, It helps.
4. You can restructure data in `find`. Let's say I just need a few fields after aggregation from an array field.
5. You cannot find a particular array or object element matching a condition using simple `find`. `elemMatch` is not that powerful.
6. You cannot group things with simple `find`

And many more.

I request you to check `aggregate operators` and relevant examples from [the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/)

Data retrieving depends on not depend on the aggregation or find. It depends on the data, hardware, and index settings.